# Migration error - The size of the index key is more than 900 bytes

Tags: mysql, migration

I'm trying to migrate from MySQL database to MSSQL.
I'm using SQL Server migration assistant for mysql and tried to 'convert schema' and run into two errors (both same):

```
The size of the index key is more than 900 bytes
```

How can I fix the specific column size to make it usable for migration?

Information about columns which cause error (From mysql db):

```
1. Varchar, Size = 1024
2. Varchar, Size = 2048
```

How can I change the column sizes so it doesnt affect data and let me successfully convert schema?

Comment: the error message is clear   .. you can't have index with a length more then 900 so you must reduce the column with for the column involved  inb index

Comment: @scaisEdge So, I could just change size to 900 and be good?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but why do you have an index on a 1024 character varchar? This seems a bit crazy to me. I would just remove the index.

Comment: @Gravy That was on Joomla db after installation. Im just trying to migrate DB servers.

Comment: @Poo123  remember that the 900 is the lenght in bytes but some  charset have more then one bytes for char ..

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned - this is a requirement of SQL Server: index key (one or multiple columns) cannot exceed 900 bytes. From your question it's not clear whether both columns are part of one single index or two separate ones. In case of the former - you will need to make sure that length of such a compound key does not exceed 900 bytes.

You can find more information on the limit [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar problem, but with Drupal. My approach to fixing this issue:

1. Install vanilla version of the CMS and make it work with MS SQL Server.
2. Check the tables that are throwing that error and check what Joomla sets as the length value for that field in MSSQL by default.
3. Apply those changes for those fields in SSMA before sync.
4. Win.